# React-native iOS, Async storage error: "Invalid key - must be at least one character. Key: "

Tags: ios, react-native, asyncstorage

I want to store a JSON object using Async Storage for my react-native app in android and iOS. I stringify the object and store it using Async Storage as it can only store strings. The app works fine in android but throws an error in iOS. The error is as follows:

```
Error: {
  key = "";
  message = "Invalid key - must be at least one character.  Key: ";
}

RCTMakeAndLogError
    RCTUtils.m:394
RCTErrorForKey
-[RCTAsyncLocalStorage _writeEntry:changedManifest:]
-[RCTAsyncLocalStorage multiSet:callback:]
__invoking___
-[NSInvocation invoke]
-[NSInvocation invokeWithTarget:]
-[RCTModuleMethod invokeWithBridge:module:arguments:]
facebook::react::RCTNativeModule::invokeInner(unsigned int, folly::dynamic const&&)
facebook::react::RCTNativeModule::invoke(unsigned int, folly::dynamic&&, int)::$_0::operator()() const
invocation function for block in facebook::react::RCTNativeModule::invoke(unsigned int, folly::dynamic&&, int)
_dispatch_call_block_and_release
_dispatch_client_callout
_dispatch_queue_serial_drain
_dispatch_queue_invoke
_dispatch_queue_override_invoke
_dispatch_root_queue_drain
_dispatch_worker_thread3
_pthread_wqthread
start_wqthread
```

My search led me to the iOS implementation of Async Storage for react-native [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/React/Modules/RCTAsyncLocalStorage.m#L307) but I have no knowledge about Objective-C or Swift. Would be grateful if someone can help me out here. Thanks!

**UPDATE**
I use AsyncStorage to store the values in a JS file.

Comment: Can you please add [mcve] of how you use AsyncStorage in your app

Comment: @bennygenel: Thanks for viewing my question. Referring to the link you provided, I commented all the AsyncStorage implementation in the screen where it was occuring and found the source of the problem. I have posted my answer below, please add if anything more is required in my answer. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my case, this issue occurs because I initialized the storage variables in the constants file with an empty string ("").
Now referring to the [iOS implementation of AsyncStorage](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/React/Modules/RCTAsyncLocalStorage.m#L307) we can see that the function which emits the error message, accepts a string value of NSString Object and it requires that the string must have a length greater than 1. As an empty string will have a length 0, this error occurs.
So initialize the variables with any string but an empty one.
Thanks everyone for taking the time to view this error.